# replace user_id with username in show page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, named

Hell frens

I want to show a username instead of user_id in user's show page.

For example,

a usr_id 300 for a user named harry exist in database. So how to show

> http://localhost:3000/harry

instead of

> http://localhost:3000/user/300

in the url.

Can this be done within from the routes file?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is commonly referred to as a vanity URL, and with a little caution you can handle this quite easily. First...

1. Make sure this is the last thing in your routes. You don't want your usernames overriding another controller's namespace.
2. Use a sensible exclude list to prevent users from having usernames like admin, support, official, secure, etc.

In your routes:

```
# the simple case
get '/:username' => 'users#show', :constrain => { :username => /[a-zA-Z-]+/ }

# ...with vanity_url_path(@user) helpers
get '/:username' => 'users#show', :as => 'vanity_url'

# or routing something more complicated with all the default resourceful routes
resources :users, :path => '/:username'

# or even just defining a bunch of routes for users with this format
controller :users, :path => '/:username' do
  get '/profile', :action => :profile    #=> /johnsmith/profile => UsersController#profile
end
```

In the above code, I avoided duplicating the `:constrain` option for each route for clarity. You will want to adjust the regular expression to match your usernames, and then make sure you do have it on whichever route you go with.

If this is going to be the default way of accessing users from within your application (ie. not just a convenient way to access the profile of a user), you will want to override the `to_param` method on your Users model. This allows you to use the `url_for` helpers like `form_for @user` without specifying additional arguments.

```
class User
  def to_param
    username
  end
end
```

Another quick tip: if you're playing with your routes and trying to do anything more than the basics, be sure to call `$ rake routes` often from the command line to see what routes Rails currently recognizes. Cleaning up ones you don't need is good to do, too. ;)

Comment: Ya its seems to replace id(300) with name **harry** but also gave error saying no record found with id harry.I have pasted "get '/:username' => 'users#show', :constrain => { :username => /[a-zA-Z-]+/ }" to bottom of route file and added to_params to my User model
Am i missing something or have i done something wrong?

Comment: @Gagan You still need to update your controller methods to find the user from the username parameter. The default is something like `User.find(params[:id])` which expects numeric primary-key ids. You want something like `User.find_by_username(params[:username])` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have /:username, then try this on your routes.rb file (THIS SHOULD BE THE LAST LINE OF THE BLOCK!  - Last route created!)

```
match "/:id", :to => "users#show", :as => :friendly_user
```

Then, just to make it less horrible, you can use [the make_permalink gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/make_permalink) to create friendly url-names easily and override the to_param method in your model

```
# models/user.rb
make_permalink :username    

def to_param
  permalink
end
```

And to make it even better, override the User.find method to work by permalink or by id

```
def self.find(query)
  self.find_by_username(query) || super(query)
end
```

That will work for User.find(1) or User.find(my_username).

Hope that helps,

Nicolás Hock Isaza

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in routes.rb

```
map.user_permalink 'users/:user_name', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

later in views use it like this:

```
<%= link_to user.name, user_permalink_path(user.user_name.parameterize) %>
```

I'm not sure if code will work simply by paste it, but you get the point :)

Answer (score 0):

**For rails 7:**

1. `In config/routes.rb`, add:

```
resources :user, param: :username
```

2. In `app/models/user.rb`, add:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```